# Taking the time average of the product of two waves

Tags: average

How might one go about calculating the time average of the product of two identical waves with different phases? For example, what would be the time average of:

$$ \cos(k x-w t) \cdot \cos(kx-wt+a) $$

and how would you get it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function is fully periodic, which means that your average integral is just an average integral over the fundamental domain.

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_n \frac{\int_0^n cos(kx-wt)cos(kx-wt+a) dt}{n} &= \lim_n \frac{\int_{-n}^n cos(kx-wt)cos(kx-wt+a) dt}{2n}\\
&= \frac{\int_{0}^{2 \pi/w} cos(kx-wt)cos(kx-wt+a) dt}{\frac{2\pi}{w}} \,
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Re-writing the ingtegrand via $\cos(A)\cos(B) = \frac{1}{2}[\cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B)]$ leads to a useful simplification with the answer depending only on $\cos(a)$.